# About 2 operators such that $X*(Y+Z) = (X*Y)+(X*Z)$ , $W+(U+V)\neq (W+U)+V$

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, binary-operations, nonassociative-algebras

This question is a follow-up and analogue of a previous very similar question.
I have to seperate questions since it is a bit of a rule ; 1 question at a time , hence this seperate one.
Looking at the other analogue question is not neccessary and can be ignored but for those who care here it is :

[About 2 operators and $A*(B+C) =(A+B)*(A+C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627930/about-2-operators-and-abc-abac)

Anyway,

Consider $2$ distinct binary operators defined for a finite set with $n$ elements.

Operator $*$ behaves like a commutative latin quandle :

$$x*x = x$$

$$a*b=b*a$$

$$a*(b*c)=(a*b)*(a*c)$$

And forms a latin square.

Commutative operator $+$ behaves like

$$A*(B+C) =(A*B)+(A*C)$$

$$X+Y = Y+X$$

And forms a latin square.

Question :

Is $+$ neccessarily associative ?

What are examples of strict non-associative or strict associative ones if they exist ?
( strict mean always that property for every pair of elements )

---

The special cases where the quandle has no subquandle is perhaps interesting.
( this happens if $n$ is prime but that is not a neccessary condition , it is similar to subgroups basically )

---

ps: do not confuse with bi-quandles as most define them.

---

Remarks :

Also note the number of solutions $(*,+)$ for a set with $n$ elements is a bit of a mystery for me , Im not even sure *with all these restrictions given* that every $n$ has such a pair of operators.
Not even for sufficiently large $n$.

But that is not the main question but just related.
Unless there are no solutions $(*,+)$ for $n$ or only for finitely many $n$ then it becomes very important.

---

Comment: You may have noticed this but: Consider $a*(a+a)=a*a+a*a=a+a$. Since $*$ is a Latin square, there is exactly one $x$ st $x(a+a)=a+a$; and we know that $(a+a)*(a+a)=a+a$; thus $x=a+a$ and so $a=a+a$.

Comment: What if $+$ is the same as $*$?

Comment: @AlexK yes good point. I forgot to mention distict. I thought I did , but I did not lol. Anyway if $+ = *$ that is not so interesting. It literally reduces to a single operator then.